# Find out which program made chrome open

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

On Skype, someone sends me website link... I click those and Chrome opens up showing the page.

Is there an event/hook/listener for chrome extension to show that the link was clicked on Skype?

In other words, find out which program made the chrome open from a Chrome extension.

Checked a bit around but couldn't find anything.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  That information isn't recorded anywhere.  And it isn't a Chrome extension.  It's just one process launching another process.